# Sending commands to google assistant using script instead of mic

Tags: raspberry-pi3, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I have configured Google Assistant SDK in Raspberry Pi 3 and demo application is working fine. Is there any way to send “OK Google, Example Command” to Google Assistant SDK using Python script? Or it will only take input from Mic?

I am planning to write tiny mobile application which will send commands to my Raspberry Pi google assistant application.

Comment: Well, you can pre-record and save a ready audio file to send for whatever "example command"

Comment: Any updates on this problem?
I am looking to integrate the text commands in my js app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*UPDATE*: even if it is an old question, here is the latest update.

It is now possible using the ***v1alpha2*** version. The gRPC message `AssistConfig` is defined as an union where you can choose between an *audio out config* or a *text query*.

---

If you are using the **python** library, see the [`AssistConfig`](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/reference/rpc/google.assistant.embedded.v1alpha2#assistconfig). Here is an example of config using a text query (adapted from the [`pushtotalk.py` sample, line 183](https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/blob/master/google-assistant-sdk/googlesamples/assistant/grpc/pushtotalk.py)):

```python
config = embedded_assistant_pb2.AssistConfig(
        # instead of audio_in_config
        # note: no need to use 'OK google'
        text_query = "who are you ?", 
        audio_out_config=embedded_assistant_pb2.AudioOutConfig(
            encoding='LINEAR16',
            sample_rate_hertz=self.conversation_stream.sample_rate,
            volume_percentage=self.conversation_stream.volume_percentage,
        ),
        dialog_state_in=dialog_state_in,
        device_config=embedded_assistant_pb2.DeviceConfig(
            device_id=self.device_id,
            device_model_id=self.device_model_id,
        )
    )
```

If you are using **golang**, [here is the link to the godoc](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/assistant/embedded/v1alpha2#AssistConfig).

Comment: Can it read some text instead of the query `text_query = "who are you ?"`?

Answer (score 0):

The current release of the Assistant SDK (Alpha v1) only supports sending and receiving audio. This is a frequent request, however, and we'll see what they provide in future updates.